# Set object according to obstacle in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want put an object at side of each obstacle that player can take cover there. for do this, i calculated position for one of obstacle that work well, but when obstacle is greater or smaller, this calculation won't work for them. i need a way for do that for all obstacle.

These pictures show my mean:

[Image 1 - Correct Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Jpg.png)

[Image 2 - Incorrect Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIusz.png)

also this is my code:

```
        Vector3 ObjectPos = TakeCoverSign.transform.position;            
        Vector3 ObjectSize = TakeCoverSign.transform.lossyScale;
        Vector3 ObstaclePos = ObstacleList[0].position;
        ObjectPos.z = (ObstaclePos.z + ObstaclePos.z / 2) - (ObjectSize.z + ObjectSize.z / 2) + navAgent.radius;

        TakeCoverSign.transform.position = ObjectPos;
```

Comment: Have you tried local positioning instead of global? because you need to set the object's position **relative** to the obstacle, so you need to calculate it locally and relatively. You can also add this new object to the child of the obstacle and then add a relative position to it which I think works just fine.

Comment: yes i tried, but both has same result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue comes with how you are adding the Navmesh Agent's radius - if you add something to a negative value that will reduce it, meaning it will be within cover.

**Here are some visual examples:**

[image: Left of cover, plus agent.radius]
[image: Right of cover, plus agent radius]

So as we can see, what we need to actually do, is depending on whether the value we have for our target position is either greater or less than the center of the object, adjust accordingly to accommodate for it:

[image: Left and right of cover, with correct radius calculation]

**Code**

So to ensure it works properly, here is the code I suggest you implement:

```
takeCoverSign.transform.position = (takeCoverSign.transform.position.z + takeCoverSign.transform.position.z / 2) - (takeCoverSign.transform.lossyScale.z + takeCoverSign.transform.lossyScale.z / 2);

if(takeCoverSign.transform.position.z - obstacleList[0].position.z > 0)
{
    takeCoverSign.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z += -navAgent.radius);
}
else
{
    takeCoverSign.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z += navAgent.radius);
}
```

Also, take note of how I have renamed your variables. This is [camel casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), and is recommended for variables.

I have also removed the unnecessary variable assignments, unless there is a reason to abstract the calculation, you may as well use the references to the variables.

**EDIT: Adjusted the above answer to create a new Vector3 to assign to the position, rather than attempting to directly modify a return value.**

Comment: Thanks Jared. it's seem Wrong. also we need other variable for control z position. because in unity you can't change (x or y or z) axis value directly. and need to store it into temp variable and change there. camel casing is good idea. :)

Comment: @Behdadsoft in addition to your message as an answer below, the issue is how you are calculating the actual width. The scale of an object does not always represent it's actual width, so lossyScale is not always relevant.

Answer (score 0):

@jared

In unity, the code must write like below. but this code gave me wrong result.

**NOTE: My problem is that, this code not work for any obstacle size and position. this code exactly work like my own code.**

```
    Vector3 TempPos = takeCoverSign.transform.position;
    TempPos.z = (obstacleList[0].position.z + obstacleList[0].position.z / 2) - (takeCoverSign.lossyScale.z + takeCoverSign.lossyScale.z / 2);

    if (TempPos.z - obstacleList[0].position.z > 0)
    {
        TempPos.z += -navAgent.radius;
    }
    else
    {
        TempPos.z += navAgent.radius;
    }

    takeCoverSign.transform.position = TempPos;
```

Comment: Just a heads up bud, you should avoid adding additional context via answers, this should be done in the comments.

Comment: Based on your message here though, it looks like the way you are calculating the original position must be off.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. i will be try calculate again.